# UIButtons text not wrapping consistenly

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Final stages of my app and I cannot solve this text issue. See the pictures to understand the issue. The UIButton are not displaying text consistently

[image]

Current code

```
for (idx,button) in buttonHandler.enumerate() {
    button.setTitle(answers[idx], forState: .Normal)
    button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Left
    button.enabled = true
    button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)    
}
```

Ive tried to change the `.numberOfLines` and the `.ByWordWrapping` and it does not change things. 
Thanks

Comment: Looks weird, did you check are the texts correct and contains red parts?

Comment: The wrapping looks correct for your setting.  It is wrapping at word breaks.  What exactly do you think is wrong?  Is it the red text?  If so, do you need the button labels to support attributed text, or should all buttons have the same font / size /  color?

Comment: The issue is that the text in red is omitted, I added it in Photoshop to illustrate the problem. The last example shows an answer that takes up 2 lines of text correctly. I need all of them to behave that way and I cannot make it happen.